# How to handle expiring refresh tokens in spring boot rest template client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm working on integrating a third party API in my spring boot application.

How the third party API authentication works:

1. After initial authorisation, I'm provided with refresh token and
   access token that expires after a given time
2. After the access token expires I use the refresh token to get a new access token AND a new refresh token

With the current access token I can make calls to the API.

Is there a way to seamlessly handle such case using RestTemplate?

I've tried handling this case manually, so if I got 401 back from the API I sent a refresh token request, rewrote the keys I got back and retried the request, not really sure how to handle storing the api keys in case I need to restart the server.

Comment: When is access token getting expired? Ie is it something like after 30 mins of inactivity or exactly at after 30 mins? The provider should be able to answer/specified in the contract. Base from that you should consistently know when to send the "re-authentication"

Comment: How about [Oauth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) ? Take a look

Answer (score 13):

This is easily done with a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` in which you can replace a requests header if e.g. a `401` occured:

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
  HttpRequest request, 
  byte[] body, 
  ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
       request.getHeaders().replace("Auth-Header", getNewToken());
       return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
    return response;
}
```

See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor) for further guidance.

Comment: how would you put all of it inside the IOC ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are probably providing your `RestTemplate` as a `@Bean` which can autowire your custom `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` in its factory method

Comment: my RestTemplate must be a bean since i m using apiclient generated from swagger plugin, at that moment i must inject the interceptor in the resttemplate after spring boot app has been initialized, i got to solve it

Comment: This solution causes thread locks on the restTemplate, seems like a bad solution. (Only difference is that I add the token before the first request also)

Comment: Thread get locked because response before UNAUTHARIZATION check is still there I assume. Need to close response inside if check: response.close();